# Iterative lambda not behaving as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, pyqt5

This question has been asked a thousand times, and I do apologize for the repetition however it's evident to me I am missing a fundamental piece of this puzzle.

I've got a pretty standard iterative qtbutton setup:

```
for i, button in enumerate(qtbuttons):
    button.clicked.connect(lambda i=i: doTheThing(i))

def doTheThing(index):
    print("Button pushed has index %s"%index)
```

My understanding was that by doing `lambda i=i:`, the lambda would retain the index at the time it was assigned, thereby preventing all buttons from returning the last index. What I ended up with was the exact opposite issue. All buttons now return "0".

I also tried string formatting, something pointed to me in another thread, which did not work either.

I was working off of the info in this thread [Python's lambda iteration not working as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155603/pythons-lambda-iteration-not-working-as-intended) which is now 10 years old.

If possible, I'd really like to know:

1. Why this is returning "0" for each button.
2. How to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: I suggest you use `lambda k=i: doTheThing(k)` - using `i` to represent two different variables is not likely to work and even if it does it will confuse the hell out of most people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked:

> void QAbstractButton::clicked(bool checked = false)

When `clicked` is emitted, it calls the connected function and passes the `checked` value to it.

Since your function has one optional parameter `i`, the `checked` value is bound as an argument to this parameter and if it is `False` (usually the case for normal push buttons), `i` appears as `0` ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guaranteed-by-the)).

You need to pass a function that accepts *two* arguments; one is the `checked` value that is emitted from the signal, and the other one is `i`:

```
for i, button in enumerate(qtbuttons):
    button.clicked.connect(lambda checked, i=i: doTheThing(i))
```

The `checked` value can just be ignored by the function if it is not needed.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you! When I did string formatting I saw the "False" and was very confused, this explains where it came from!